# SharePointWebControls:UserField does not work in Script Editor

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, person-or-group, script-editor-webpart

I am trying to add the following code:

```
<SharePointWebControls:UserField FieldName="Site Owner" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:UserField>
```

in a Script Editor Web Part.

However, nothing happens.

Does the Script Editor Web Part support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Script Editor web part just supports HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery code, it is not available for SharePoint server web controls.

You can add the code into the page via SharePoint Designer 2013 instead of Script Editor web part.

A demo for your reference:
[image]

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I get it now. I would have to create a custom webpart that can accommodate what I'm trying to do.